# Basic Entity Framework Questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4

I have an existing database, which I have been happily accessing using LINQtoSQL.  Armed with Sanderson's MVC3 book I thought I'd have a crack at EF4.3, but am really fighting to get even basic functionality working.

Working with SQL 2008, VS2010, the folder architecture appears to be:

```
ABC.Domain.Abstract
ABC.Domain.Concrete
ABC.Domain.Concrete.ORM
ABC.Domain.Entities
```

Per examples, repository interfaces are abstract, actual repositories are concrete.  Creating EDMX from the existing database puts that in the ORM folder and the Entities holds the classes I designed as part of the domain.  So far so good.

However!  I have not once persuaded the deceptively simple EfDbContext : DbContext class, with method to work...

```
public DbSet<ABC.Domain.Entities.Person> Person { get { return _context.Persons; }}
```

It complains about missing keys, that Person is not a entity class, that it cannot find the conceptual model, and so on.

1. Considering I have a basic connectionstring in the web.config, why is not creating a model on the fly to do simple matching?
2. Should the ORM folder exist, or should it simply be Concrete?  (I have a .SQL subfolder for LINQtoSQL concret so it suits me to have .ORM but if it's a flaw, let's fix it).
3. Should I have my homespun entities AND the automatically produced ones or just one set?
   The automatic ones inherit from EntityObject, mine are just POCO or POCO with complexTypes, but do not inherit from anything.
4. What ties the home designed Domain.Entities.Person type to the Persons property of the Context?
   Sanderson's book implies that the matching is implicit if properties are identical, which they are, but that does not do it.
5. The app.config has an EF flavoured connection string in it, the web.config has a normal connection string in it.  Which should I be using - assuming web.config at the moment - so do I delete app.config?

Your help is appreciated. Long time spent, no progress for some days now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is overly broad. Please have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I know.  But!  I doubt that going deeper than the basic concept will help much!  The code is academic compared with the principle of the set up. Anyone familiar with Sanderson's MVC3 book ought to be able to infer the principle features of the solution by folder architecture - and since I cannot see any way to be sure that is correct, I have no way to ask specific code based questions.

Comment: I hoped you might ask me a particular "have you checked..." sort of reply and I could find the culprit.  Above are simply my theories for lines of enquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What ties the home designed Domain.Entities.Person type to the Persons
>   property of the Context?

You seem to have a misunderstanding here. Your domain entities *are* the entities for the database. There aren't two sets. If you actually want to have two sets of object classes (for whatever reason) you must write any mapping between the two manually. EF only knows about the classes which are part of the entity model.

You should also - if you are using EF 4.3 - apply the DbContext Generator T4 template to the EDMX file. Do not work with `EntityObject` derived entities! It is not supported with `DbContext`. The generator will build a set of POCO classes and prepare a derived `DbContext`. This set of POCO classes are the entities the DbContext will only know about and they should be your only set of domain entities.

The created `DbContext` will contain simple `DbSet` properties with automatic getters and setters...

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

...and the `Person` class will be created as POCO as well.

Comment: @David: Entity Framework has generally two approaches: You have seen the first, the older one, that is: entities are derived from `EntityObject` (= not persistence agnostic). The second way is using POCOs (= persistence agnostic), which is the prefered way (by most EF users and MS development team as well) since version EF 4.1 (already starting with EF 4.0). There isn't a "mirror" between POCO and non-POCO. EF just has the ability to persist POCOs. The entities don't "tell" EF how they have to be persisted, instead EF "infers" persistence logic from name conventions or explicit configuration.

Comment: The newer approach is the one I am aiming for. Just POCO. Of course, I have the DB already, so it does not have an entirely free hand.  Can I assume then the process is to create an object model in code, create an EDMX file from that, then map that to an existing database?  What I was doing was updating the model from the DB.  This creates the inherited types.  I can clear it away at this point and start over with little harm done.

Comment: @David: Not exactly. You don't need an EDMX file if you start from code (="Code-First" development). You just have POCO classes, a DbContext class, mapping configuration code and the database. Here is a walkthrough for EF Code-First: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Comment: @David: Probably just for the case that you want to add custom code to your classes which shouldn't be overwritten when you run the generator again. BTW: If you proceed, please ask better new questions rather than cluttering this comment section into an endless thread. You can also pick up one of the answers to "accept" it (click white check mark on the left of the answers). It's good practice here if your question gets answered. You don't need to do it at once and can wait for more answers, but sooner or later you should accept one (unless no answer did really help you).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have ticked your response for highlighting the introductory article link.

Answer (score 0):

Download the entity framework power tools:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Right click in your project to 'reverse engineer an existing database' it will create the code classes for you. No need to use EDMX ,and this method will create the DbContext derived class for you

Comment: It will, if by chance you are in PA I'll be doing a session on this (EF in web applications) next Tuesday near Bethlehem or a similar session for VSLive Las Vegas at the end of this month.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions here and you won't get an answer, but I'll stick my 5 pence for what it's worth.

> Sanderson's MVC3 book

Your problems are not to do with MVC3, they are to do with Entity Framework and data persistence layer.

> ABC.Domain.Abstract ABC.Domain.Concrete ABC.Domain.Concrete.ORM
>   ABC.Domain.Entities

Can you say why this is separated in such a way? I would argue and say that ABC.Domain should contain your POCOs independent of your persistence layer (EF) and your presentation layer (MVC). Your list implies that your domain contains ORM and your data access entities. I'm not arguing here, what I'm trying to say, is that you need to understand what you really need.

At the end of a day, I'm certain that a simple example would suffice with ABC.DataAccess, ABC.Domain and ABC.Site.

Do you understand why repositories are abstract and concrete? If you don't, then leave out interfaces and see whether you can improve it with interfaces later.

> Person is not a entity class, that it cannot find the conceptual
>   model, and so on.

Now, there are multiple ways you can get EF to persist data for you. You can use code first, where, as the name implies, you will write code first, and EF will generate database, relations and all the relevant constraints for you.

You can use database first, where EF will generate relevant class and data access related objects from your database. This is less preferable method for me, as it relies heavily upon your database structure.

You can use model first, where you will design your class in EDMX designer and it will then generate relevant SQL for you.

All of these might sound like a bit of black box, but for what you are trying to achieve all of them will work. EDMX is a good way to learn and there are many step by step tutorials on ASP.Net.

> but if it's a flaw, let's fix it).

You will have to fix and refactor yourself, there is no other way to improve in my honest opinion. I can give you a different folder/namespace structure, but there will always be a "better" one.

> Should I have my homespun entities AND the automatically produced ones
>   or just one set?

Now this depends on the model that you have chosen. Database first, code first, code only and whatever else is there. If you are following domain driven development, then you will have to work with classes, that represent your business logic and that are not tied up to your data persistence layer or presentation layers, therefore POCO is a way forward.

> What ties the home designed Domain.Entities.Person type to the Persons

Now this again depends on the model that you are using.

> The app.config and web.config

When you are running your web application, the connection string from web application will be used. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

> Your help is appreciated. Long time spent, no progress for some days
>   now.

General advise, leave MVC alone for the time being. Get it to work in a console application and make sure you feel comfortable with options offered in EF. Good luck :)

Comment: Sounds a lot like Domain Drive Development For Dummies, does your project really need DDD? check the requirements when DDD will save you complexity thus time, because most projects can be done with an easy client server layer architecture

Comment: Have you decided what model you want to be using? I'm a bit confused whether you are using model first or code only?

Comment: I started with code first, could not get it working.  Explored designing things with EDMX graphically.  And then in the end, worked the existing DB into a model and back up with codeGen T4 tools, per advice above.  It is working (kinda...) for the moment.  This did not give me what I was expecting, but a second set of classes.  So for the moment I am using the T4 gen'd ones to move on a step or two in the visual layer.

Comment: You should be taking database backups frequently. There will always be a risk of you losing database and some data. Code first examples normally have implementation of a "Seed" method which auto-populates your database with some test data. You can then run seed each time you run application, or make changes to your model. If you have any specific questions regarding your code, then post them here, otherwise I think it's a conversation that can go on forever :)

Comment: Solved.  Please see my comment about connectionStrings.  

And thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to why nothing worked code-first...

...turned out to be a reference to System.Data.EntityClient in the connection string, which ought to have read System.Data.SqlClient.

Without this provider entry being correct, it was unable to work code-first.

Finding which connectionString it was using was a case of deliberately mis-spelling a keyword in the connections there were to choose from - they all were named correctly - but were in app.config, and 2 places in the web.config.  With a distinct naming error, when the application threw an error trying to create the domain model, it was easy to identify which connection string my derived DbContext class was using.  Correcting the ProviderName made all the difference.

Code-first is now working just fine, with seeded values on model changes.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the folder architecture makes no difference in this scenario - it affects namespaces but that's about it.